# jq でオブジェクトからそのすべての値へフィルタするには？

Tags: jq

jq で、オブジェクトから、その値すべてに変換するにはどうやったらいいですか？

オブジェクトから、鍵一覧は `keys` フィルタで実現できるようですが。。

Comment: `jq '.[]' JSON_FILE` とすれば良いかと思いますが、そういう事ではないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.[]` フィルタは、オブジェクトに対してはその値すべてを出力するんですね。。これがまさにほしかったものです。

Comment: `keys` のように配列として取り出したいのであれば、`map(.)` とか `[.[]]` とかですかね。

Comment: すべてを出力なら  `jq '.' file` ではないでしょうか？

Comment: @take88 オブジェクト(マップ) の value 一覧の取得がやりたいことです。 cdr の一覧です。